# How many questions and answers are asked in one day at Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, statistics

I was wondering how many question and answers are posted each day at Stack Overflow?

I have gone through [how many questions are opened Daily on Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/46748/231490), but I didn't get a perfect answer.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites#users 7.2k questions/day

Comment: @Bart: what about answers?

Comment: No i was not able to get it , even not (number of )questions in your given link.where you find it.?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OS19vEz.png

Comment: is there any value for number of answers per day?

Comment: @Virussmca see the math that I did in my answer :-D

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59302/questions-and-answers-per-month

Comment: Ahhh `CASE`... I am so used ti MySQL that I used `IF` and it kept failing and I did not know why.... @Geobits

Answer (score 21, accepted):

***For questions:***

<sub>300 / hour</sub>

#### 7.2K / day

### 72K / 10 days

## 720K / 100 days

## **2.628M / year**

[Source](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users)

---

***For answers:***

Figure we do the math:

There are about 300 questions per hour -- 77% of which have at least one answer (based on [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites#users)), so that is about 230. Half of that 230 have at least 3 answers, so that is another 230, about an eighth of the original 150 *may* have 4+ answers which is about another 100 - 300 answers... So **230 + 230 + 200** *ish* is about 660 answers
, **so about**:

<sub>660 / hour</sub>

#### 15.84K / day

### 158.4K / 10 days

## 1.584M / 100 days

## **5.782M / year**

---

## Based on **real data** from the past year (Sept 2012 - Sept 2013):

[Source](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142554/system-posts-on-so?opt.withExecutionPlan=true)

There have been **2,170,441** Questions over the past year which calculates to about:

<sub>~247 / hour</sub>

#### ~5.946K / day

### ~59.46K / 10 days

## ~594.6K / 100 days

## **~2.17M / year**

---

There have been **3,275,577** Answers over the past year which calculates to about:

<sub>~374 / hour</sub>

#### ~8.974K / day

### ~89.74K / 10 days

## ~897.4K / 100 days

## **~3.276M / year**

Comment: I updated my answer more @Bart **MATH!!**

Comment: Pshh, math .... as if that has even proven anything. P.s. you might want to check your figures at the end there ...

Comment: @Bart hmmm where did I go wrong? Did I do maths wrong?!?!

Comment: 10.8k / 10 days --> ??? / 100 days

Comment: 10.8K * 10 === 1.08 million... no? Unless I don't know my tens multiplication table.... **CRAP!!!** You are right!!

Comment: @Bart silly me :-P the 1st number was wrong and the last one was right ^_^ I fixed it!! YAY~~~ ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: That greats, i doesn't even guess these much answers are given..

Comment: Don't tell me you came up with the correct last figure based on wrong assumptions about the previous ones. I should really have you look at my code. I never get stuff to work when it really shouldn't!

Comment: @Bart lol I got the last figure first then did division. I put the decimals in the wrong places :-P

Comment: What percentage of these questions remain on the site? I suppose most of them get closed and deleted.

Comment: @Calmarius that is true. but they still figure into the calculations I assume...

Comment: Is there a basis for "half of which have at least one answer..." and the following numbers or are they just an assumption? That would imply that the answer/question ratio is dropping, since overall the site has 11M / 5.9M answers to questions.

Comment: @Geobits I am making complete guesstimates. Given that there are 300 questions per hour.

Comment: Gotcha, I wasn't sure if there was a place that showed the number of answers or what.

Comment: @Geobits also if you look at my guesstimates they are fairly close to the real numbers for how many answers there **actually** are on the site over the past 5 year period.

Comment: @Geobits updated with new numbers  based on 77% answered as opposed to 50%

Comment: So, TL;DR: A lot.

Comment: Haha yes, basically that much @RocketHazmat ^_^

Comment: 77% is the rate of questions with (at least) one answer. And it doesn't match how many answers questions get, since many questions get 3-4 answers, while others get zero. The reality is that there are more answers provided than questions asked, just 23% have zero answers. See the other answers.

Comment: @jmac Exactly and if you look at my calculations I factor that all in :-)

Comment: Wow... real data is much less than I guesstimated @Bart

Comment: What is it with you and this relentless focus on proof and facts @amanap? Figures should be fudged and pulled out of thin air to make ourselves look better. That's how you do it!

Answer (score 3):

From August - September 13, [there were 306,484 answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142530/system-average-scores-for-stackoverflow?opt.withExecutionPlan=true), which makes about 9,886 answers per day.

Comment: Does that query only count answers? Or both questions and answers?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA `where PostTypeId = 2` so it means only answers, I'll fix the post.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: yes, I did mean answers, my bad.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I hope you don't mind that I updated your query to use in my updated answer.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: of course not.

Answer (score 2):

From September 13th, to October 13th.

- [296,291 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2013-9-13..2013-10-13)
- [211,557 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2013-9-13..2013-10-13)

This obviously varies greatly depending on the number of weekdays, national holidays, etc. You will have less questions/answers on a weekend than a weekday, more within US working hours than outside, etc.

Comment: This is also **not** including any deleted posts...

Comment: Correct. It does not. (I do not think that deleted posts would be as consistent since many deleted posts would be spam which I can't imagine is steady...that is a totally separate good question though). @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA